# if $ab = ba$ for all $a \in X$ and for all $b \in X$ then $\langle X \rangle$ is abelian subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

if $X \subseteq G$ such that $\forall a,b \in X$ we have $ab = ba$ then we should prove that $\langle X \rangle$ is an abelian subgroup of G.

its abviouse that $\langle X \rangle$ is subgroup of $G$. for proving abelian part we have that $X \subseteq C_G(X) \leq G$ there for $\langle X \rangle \subseteq C_G(X)$.

if we show $\langle X \rangle \subseteq C_G(\langle X \rangle)$ then $\forall g \in \langle X \rangle : g \in C_G(\langle X \rangle)\Rightarrow \forall g \in \langle X \rangle \quad \forall h \in \langle X \rangle : hg = gh$.

is this proof correct? and how can I show that $\langle X \rangle \subseteq C_G(X)$ then  $\langle X \rangle \subseteq C_G(\langle X \rangle)$ ?

Comment: It is in your title: fix $a\in X$; for all $b\in X$, we have $ab=ba$, doesn't it mean that $a\in C_G(X)$?

Comment: What is $\langle X\rangle $?

Comment: @karo Are you familiar with this characterisation of the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $X\neq\emptyset$? $$\langle X\rangle:=\{ a_1a_2\cdots a_k\,:\, k\in\mathbb N\wedge (\forall i,\ a_i\in X\vee a_i^{-1}\in X)\}$$

Comment: @learnmore its the subgroup generated by X

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes, should I use this ?

Comment: Personally, that's how I'd do it. Step (1): in general, if $x,y$ commute, then $y$ commutes with $x^{-1}$; Step (2): using the characterisation and step (1), all the elements of $X$ commute with the elements of $\langle X\rangle$; Step (3): with the same argument, all the elements of $\langle X\rangle$ commute with all the elements of $\langle X\rangle$ (or, as you noticed, step (2) is *exactly* saying that $\langle X\rangle\subseteq C_G(X)$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Order theoretic one-inch punch

The centralizer has the property that $Y\subseteq C_G(X)\iff X\subseteq C_G(Y)$. From $X\subseteq C_G(X)$ you get $\langle X\rangle\subseteq C_G(X)$, and from the property just mentioned you get $X\subseteq C_G(\langle X \rangle)$. It follows that $\langle X\rangle\subseteq C_G(\langle X \rangle)$, and that amounts to $\langle X\rangle$ being Abelian.

### Order-theoretic judo chop

I think there are two things that can help you:

1. the centralizer map $C_G(-)$ is an order reversing map on nonempty subsets of $G$. That is, if $X\subseteq Y\subseteq G$, then $C_G(Y)\subseteq C_G(X)$; and
2. the centralizer map $C_G(-)$ is "extensive" in the sense that $C_G(C_G(X))\supseteq X$ for any nonempty subset $X$ of a group $G$ even outside the context of this problem.

Since you know the hypothesis gives you $X\subseteq C_G(X)$, by definition of $\langle X\rangle$ and the fact that the centralizer is a subgroup, you have that $$\langle X \rangle\subseteq C_G(X)$$

Applying the order-reversing property, we also have $$C_G(C_G(X))\subseteq C_G(\langle X\rangle)$$

By the first property I mentioned,

$$X\subseteq C_G(C_G(X))\subseteq C_G(\langle X\rangle)$$

Again, by definition of $\langle X\rangle$, we can conclude that $$\langle X\rangle\subseteq C_G(\langle X\rangle)$$

This says that every element of the group centralizes the group, and so the group is abelian.

### Group theoretic [Haymaker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/haymaker) punch

If you are more comfortable thinking of $\langle X\rangle$ as words made up of symbols from $X$ and their inverses, then you can also note that $\{x^{-1}\mid x\in X\}$ also centralizes $X$, and therefore all such words would have to commute with each other. This would probably involve induction on the length of words.